# CSS gradients for firefox 3.5

Tags: firefox, css, gradient

What I'm trying to accomplish is creating a gradient using only css... What I'm doing works in all browsers except firefox 3.5...here's the code:

```
 #gradient {
      color: #fff;
      height:50px;
      padding:0;
      width:940px;
      margin:0 auto;            
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #CFE782 0%, #9BCB2A 2%,#5DA331 97%, #659635 100%);/* For Mozilla/Gecko (Firefox etc) */
 }
```

I left out the background for the other browsers... SO here's my question...

Does anyone know why this is not working in Firefox 3.5 and what would work???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, the reason why its not working is because `-moz-linear-gradient` was only introduced in Firefox 3.6.